# Disabling acces to previous pages in Webform

Tags: webforms

I have a multi-page survey where I need to prevent participants from paging back through the survey and changing his/her answers.

The only thing I can think of is to break the multi-page form into multiple forms.  The first form would limit the user to taking the form once and the submit button would forward the user to the second form.

It's an acceptable hack if you only need to do it once, but I would vastly prefer to do it the official way, if there is one...

Thanks!